# How to solve image resize issue in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-imagekit

I have multiple images upload in my Database, and when I am uploading image in Django then it's reducing the size of image (eg: 200km to 90 kb), but suppose if image size is `1000*800` then it's saving in the same size. I want to resize it with `600*400`, Please let me know where I am mistaking in this code.
please check my code, here are my `models.py` file

```
import sys
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='product_image',blank=False,null=True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.image = self.compressImage(self.image)
    super(ProductImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

  def compressImage(self, image):
    imageTemproary = Image.open(image)
    outputIoStream = BytesIO()
    imageTemproaryResized = imageTemproary.resize((600, 400))
    imageTemproary.save(outputIoStream, format='JPEG', quality=60)
    outputIoStream.seek(0)
    image = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream, 'ImageField', "%s.jpg" % image.name.split('.')[0],
                                         'image/jpeg', sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None)
    return image
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't pin point where the problem is, I myself is a newbie. but you can try this, it should work.

```
def compressImage(self, image):
    image_file = BytesIO(image.file.read())
    n_image = Image.open(image_file)
    n_image.thumbnail((600, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image_file = BytesIO()
    n_image.save(image_file, 'JPEG')
    return image_file
```